# Get host from IP address C

Tags: c, http-proxy

Given a url-link, I have to send a TCP request. The first thing I did, after parsing the url properly was to get the IP:

```
...
struct hostnet *host;
...
host = gethostbyname(url);
```

My question is the following: Is there any possible way to get the port of an IP address, that does **not** contain `:` to indicate it's port?

Comment: Which port? What if more than one port was open on that host?

Comment: "the port of an IP address" ? What did you mean ? what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Need to know how `url` is declared.  Need to know struct definition of `hostnet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the port of ann `http:` URL does not have a port-part, then it is expected that you'll connect at the *default* port for that schema. If you're on a Unix box, `/etc/services/` has a list, but here's an abridged version:

```
ftp     21
ssh     22
smtp    25
http    80
irc    194
imap3  220
ldap   389
https  443
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, you need a port number, but the URL does not have :port part, right?

There are default port number for each service, i.e. 80 for HTTP, 53 for DNS etc. On Unix you might want to check /etc/services and man getservbyname(3).